# How to clear the input field when click button with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

in JavaScript like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Clear the input field when you click on the button:</p>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''">Clear input field</button>

<input type="text" id="myInput">

</body>
</html>
```

How to use with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i succeeded in dom javascript, with inline onclick event

```
<input type="text" id="hdd_data_2" value="3 TB">
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('hdd_data_2').value ''">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using ng-model directive, here an example how you can implement it in your code

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <p>Clear the input field when you click on the button:</p>
  <button ng-click="clearInput()">Clear input field</button>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" ng-model="input">
</div>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.input = '';

  $scope.clearInput = function() {
     $scope.input = '';
  }
}]);
```

You can see the angularjs documentation for more examples.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller